# $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\int \:f\left(x,\:y,\:t\right)dt\right)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Is there a general formula for solving this?
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\int \:f\left(x,\:y,\:t\right)dt\right)$$

[the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUgJ6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Leibniz integral rule, also known as differentiation under the integral sign:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_{t_0}^{t_1}f(x,y,t)\,dt=\int_{t_0}^{t_1}f_x(x,y,t)
\,dt$$

Comment: Thank you so much